# R data frame, sampling with replacement while controling for two variables

Tags: r, sample, random

I have the following data frame in R, with three variables:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
frequency<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
male<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
df<-data.frame(id,frequency,male)
```

For `df` mean `frequency` is 5.5 and 50% of observations are `male`. Now I want to take a random sample with replacement from `df` and with the same size, while mean `frequency` of the new sample is 4 and `male`'s proportion remains constant.
I wonder if there is any way to do such thing in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find any particular function for what you want. But it will give the results you want. The combination of 'repeat' and if function play the same role as while loop, and other line means do sampling size of 4.

```
repeat
{
    df.sample = df[sample(nrow(df),size=4,replace=FALSE),]
    if(mean(df.sample$frequency) == 4.5 & mean(df.sample$male) == 0.5){
        break
    }
}
```

The results is

```
> df.sample
  id frequency male
   4  4         4    0
   2  2         2    0
   9  9         9    1
   3  3         3    1
```

For while  loop,

```
while(!(mean(df.sample$frequency) == 4.5 & mean(df.sample$male) == 0.5)){
    df.sample = df[sample(nrow(df),size=4,replace=FALSE),]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing: I reckon 'replace' should be =TRUE and 'size' = 10 to perfectly answer the question above.

Comment: If you change 'size = 4, replace = FALSE' to 'size = 10, replace = TRUE', you can get the result that has 10 rows, mean(frequency) = 4.5 and mean(male) = 0.5.

Comment: I just tested the code on my dataset of 100K records and it is not working. it seems that the loop solution is only good for small number of records and cannot solve the problem when we have for instance 100K records. any thoughts?

Comment: This solution may take long time for large data set and number of sample sizes. Or, there is no right sample if you set `replace = FALSE` instead of `replace = TRUE`. Did you check before testing code?